# Minimal number of 3-cycles that generates $A_n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

It is a well known fact that $A_n$ is generated by 3-cycles.

If we denote by $N$ the minimal number of 3-cycles needed to generate $A_n$, I'm looking for an estimate of such $N$ as function of $n$.

In particular my claim is that $N=O(n)$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Any help or reference is well accepted.

Comment: The exact value is $N = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ for $n \ge 3$ - see my comment on Chickenmancer's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Conrad's paper:

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf

Certainly, $A_n$ is generated by $3-$cycles. However, you may reduce this to precisely

$$\{(12i) \mid 1\leq i \leq n-2\},$$

which is minimal of length $n-2.$ This works for $n\geq 5.$

Comment: Thank's a lot! The article is very interesting and usefull not only for the question I've proposed but also for my field of study!

Comment: I sincerely recommend anything by Keith Konrad. His expository papers are superb. 

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/

Comment: This isn't the smallest number possible. You can generate $A_n$ with the $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ $3$-cycles $(1,2,3)$, $(3,4,5)$, $(5,6,7), \ldots, (n-2,n-1,n)$ (where the final two generators overlap in two points when $n$ is even).

Comment: Note also that you mean $3 \le i \le n$ rather than $1 \le i \le n-2$.